# How to switch the server in apk

Tags: android

I have one test apk which is pointing 3 different environments.

Is there any way to switch from one to another environment or Is there any app to switch between one server to another?

Thanks
Chandra

Comment: id imagine its a 'internal dev', 'client dev', 'production' setup, where it would be nice to seemlessly switch endpoints without having to recompile. Nevertheless, use a build tool such as ant, and create a build for each environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea:
You can use a webservice that will return a xml/Json containing server URL. Save this to a config file(if you want, when the app starts or from time to time) and use that in your application. Like this, you can always change your webservice to return a new URL so you can change the server like this.

I hope this idea will help you,
Arkde